# Express session does not show session variables when called from React app but does from browser

Tags: node.js, express, session, session-cookies, session-variables

I have a simple endpoint where I am trying to check if a session variable is present and return a `status(200)` if so and return a `status(401)` if not.

Right now I am simply logging the `req.session` like so.

```
app.get("/api/checkAuth", (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.session)
}
```

When I fetch this endpoint from my React app (`http://localhost:3000`) the `console.log(req.session)` in my server does not show the values even though I know that I am signed in and the variables are present.

But if I go directly to the route in my browser `http://localhost:4000/api/checkAuth` then the `console.log(req.session)` successfully logs the session values.

My React application is not showing a CORS issue.

Any ideas on what is going on?